# Propogate values based on condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

say I have pandas dataframe like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsqTH.png)

Now, I want to update all 1's to 0's if 1 has already occurred in that row. Hence the new df will look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4MRN.png)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col_A":[0, 1, 0, 1, 1], "Col_B":[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
             "Col_C":[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],"Col_D":[1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
             "Col_E":[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})
```

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to implement this in pandas. Currently I am looping over each row and then each column and then keeping a flag to check if 1 has occurred and subsequently updating the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,size = (10,10)))
print(df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
3  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
4  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
6  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
7  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
8  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1
9  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
```

---

**Solution**

[`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to performance a mask with [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df.mask(df.cumsum(axis = 1).shift(axis = 1).gt(0),0)

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
9  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

**Output OP DataFrame**

```
print(df.mask(df.cumsum(axis = 1).shift(axis = 1).gt(0),0))
   Col_A  Col_B  Col_C  Col_D  Col_E
0      0      1      0      0      0
1      1      0      0      0      0
2      0      0      0      0      1
3      1      0      0      0      0
4      1      0      0      0      0
```

**Another posible solution: [`DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)**

```
df.sub(df.cumsum(1)).add(df).clip(lower = 0)
```